# QtQuick lower() and raise() does not work while close() works properly

Tags: qt, window, stackview

I have 5 windows which i push and pop via a stackview. In the emulator the new window called by push gets on top as it should. However on my android it spawns behind the starting window. I tried using lower() to set the starting window behind the new window with no success

```
//start page
Button{myStack.push(page_2); lower()}
```

I also tried rasing the new window on completion with no success

```
//new page
Component.OnCompleted:raise()
```

However close() works properly closing the start page and thus making the new page visible.

```
//start page
Button{myStack.push(page_2); close()}
```

Qt doc goes as follows for lower()

> lower()
>
> Lowers the window in the windowing system.
>
> Requests that the window be lowered to appear below other windows.

and for raise()

> raise()
>
> Raises the window in the windowing system.
>
> Requests that the window be raised to appear above other windows.

Is my code correct? why does close() work and the others dont't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't think that Qt supports multi window on Android. One single window only.

Second - what you posted is not even valid QML code.

Third - in that case you use the the stack view within a single window, and push different GUI elements onto it. Refer to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html).

Comment: i looked it up and only androids 7.0 or higher support multi window. The emulator i was using was above 7.0 so I was working on multiple windows thinking it was fine